# Copy file from another project in a Gradle task

Tags: gradle, resources

Given is the following Gradle task:

```
task copyResource(type: Copy) {
  from('.') {
    include '../anotherProject/password.txt'
  }
  into 'build/docker'
}
```

On task execution the include is ignored. What is the correct way to reference to a file from another project directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
task copyResource(type: Copy) {
  from('../anotherProject') {
    include 'password.txt'
  }
  into 'build/docker'
}
```

or even simpler :

```
task copyResource(type: Copy) {
  from('../anotherProject/password.txt')
  into 'build/docker'
}
```